# istio: route traffic between sidecar-enabled pods and non-sidecar-enabled pods

Tags: kubernetes, containers, istio, envoyproxy

If I enable Istio on some of my apps (but not all of them) using Manual sidecar injection, can I route traffic between non-based-Istio apps and Istio-based apps? If yes, is it still true if I enable Citadel? I'm wondering because I'd like to slowly enable the sidecar injection on my apps and migrate over. Do both Istio-based-apps and non-Istio-based apps still talk to each other (within cluster) via the normal Kubernetes service objects? Is there anything else I need to do in order to allow Istio and regular services to talk to each other?

I'm new to Istio, so any context is helpful.

Comment: Answer to your questions will strongly depend on the TLS mode (authentication policy) currently set in your Istio/sidecar enabled Pods, is it STRICT or PERMISSIVE ?
Have you seen this mtls migration task ?
https://istio.io/docs/tasks/security/authentication/mtls-migration/

Comment: Thank you @Nepomucen for pointing me towards that reference. So it looks like, to allow non-sidecar services to talk to sidecar services, I need to create a destination rule with the tls trafficPolicy set to ISTIO_MUTUAL. And I need to create one such destination rule for each kubernetes service that I want to enable mutual tls on.

Comment: You should set PERMISSIVE policy as @Nepomucen mentioned,
and set a destination rule for each non-istio service with tls mode "NONE".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To highlight the proper solution to achieve your goal, as @Vadim Eisenberg mentioned:

> You should set PERMISSIVE policy and set a destination rule for each
>   non-istio service with tls mode "NONE".